# Avoid 2 nesting divs upon parent click

Tags: jquery, html

When a user clicks on the `.post` parent div; the window location is taken to the child `a.link`'s href value. However there are 2 other div's within `.post` that should avoid that functionality.

How would I go about ignoring the `.recommend` and `.new` divs within its parent `.post` div?

```
$("div.post").click(function(e){ // parent div
     e.stopPropagation();
     // avoid the .recommend and .new divs ?
     window.location = $(this).find('a.link').attr('href');
     return false;
});

-------------
<div class="post">
    <a class="link" href="{{ post.url }}">Post title</a>
    <img src="{{ post.image }}" />
    <p>{{ post.description }}</p>
    <div class="recommend">
         {{ post.recommend_form }}    
    </div>
    <div class="new">
        <p>Post a new comment</p>
        <a href="{{ post.new_comment_form }}">New</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Essentially I'd like to make the whole div clickable, yet avoiding the 2 nesting divs. Help? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I think the event contains the element actually clicked within as well as the element within which it is contained.

Comment: `<div class="post" data-url="{{ post.url }}">` could be an approach to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("div.recommend, div.new").click(function(e){ // child div
     e.stopPropagation();
     // avoid the .recommend and .new divs
});
```